# Irish Visa on a Pakistani passport with less than 6 months validity from travel dates

Tags: visas, passports, ireland, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national in a bit of confusion as I want to get my Irish visa for traveling to Dublin on 15 November 2015. (I already have a 5 Year Valid UK Visa on my current Passport)

The Irish Embassy website stated my passport needs to be valid for at least 6 months from my travel dates in order to issue the visa. My passport expire is in 25 March 2016. Which means I need to renew my Passport in order to be issued the visa for my dates of 15 November 2015.

The problem is that the Pakistani embassy do not renew the Passport in advance of 6 months. Which means I can only apply for a new passport at Pakistan embassy on or after 27 September 2015. The process takes 4 weeks (in urgent case). After which I can apply for the Irish visa. The Irish consulate state they will process the Visa in 4 weeks time.

This adds to a total of 8 weeks for the issuing of new Passport and issuing of Irish Visa. The problem is my travel dates (15 November 2015) will pass by during this 8 week process.

Any suggestions on what way I should go about this?

Thanks,
Wacko

P.S. First time on this website and first question. Hoping to contribute back also.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the Pakistani embassy do not renew the Passport in
>   advance of 6 months. Which means I can only apply for a new passport
>   at Pakistan embassy on or after 27 September 2015.

You can request an emergency passport; they will ask you for a reason and you can state that you need it for visa applications.

The other option here is that you can travel a bit (filling your passport pages) and then ask for a renewal for traveling; fortunately for me I went with this route and it worked well. You will have to use the expedite process.

I have heard that processing outside of Pakistan is quicker than within Pakistan due to the volume of requests. I had my passport done in less than a calendar month when applied for from Kuwait.

Comment: I am going to request them to issue me a passport as I need it for visa applications as you have suggested initially. I hope they can renew it 9 months in advance as I was reading in some visa application cases, some embassies renew 9 months in advance. I will go for the expedite process so hoping for the best.

Comment: If I have a valid Schengen Visa on a travel document which gets cancelled (since I get issued a new travel document), will that Schengen visa still allow me to travel to the Schengen area (keeping both my travel documents together)?